# Display Youtube video thumbnail

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have a fragment with a ScrollView and I want to display the YouTube thumbnail of a video as one of the items in the scrollview.
I looked up everywhere but couldn't understand how to, I really need the base.

Please help me, I'm stuck like this for days...

This method supposed to take the VIDEO_ID(from YouTube) and take it's thumbnail.
This thumnbail should be displayed in youTubeThumbnailView.
Here is something I tried:

```
   public void getThumbnail(){
    String VIDEO_ID = "xxxxxx";
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView = new YouTubeThumbnailView(getActivity());
    youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView)youTubeThumbnailView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    youTubeThumbnailView.//Dont know how to continue :(.
}
```

Comment: So what trouble are you having? You don't know the location of the thumbnail? it's not displaying? Share some of your code to help us help you.

Comment: Maybe you can add some code to show what you are trying to do. That makes it easier for others to help

Comment: @Duniyadnd I don't have any code that related yet. The thing is, I have a video id, and I want to get the thumbnail from Youtube.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie I don't have any code that related yet. The thing is, I have a video id, and I want to get the thumbnail from Youtube.

Comment: Not that much experience with android, maybe this url can help? http://sapandiwakar.in/streaming-youtube-videos-in-android/

Comment: @JettroCoenradie Forgot to mention xP, to our subject: Not at all, but I gotta do this Youtube thing... Thanks for the link. I'm editing the OP now with a little(very little)code I tried, Hope you guys understand and can help me :).